# Why do US House constituencies have numbers instead of names?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, voting-districts

In Canada, parliamentary ridings are given [names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canadian_federal_ridings), but in the US, members of Congress come from numbered districts, for example, California's 2nd.

For all the states I'm aware of, this also holds for state legislatures.

Why does the US use numbers? It can be hard to remember where districts are, especially if your state has more than a few.

Comment: I suspect that this is because U.S. House seats are redrawn every ten years and the equal population requirement and various other factors causes them to have little connection with "natural" boundaries with well defined names, but since this is only my speculation I won't post that as an answer unless I find a fuller answer from research. Another factor is that the U.S. has many more layers of districts - Canada is drawing on a U.K. tradition of naming districts when it has basically only one set. In the U.S. many voters are in many numbered districts for different elected bodies. I'm in 9.

Comment: @ohw I'm pretty sure provincial parliaments have different electoral boundaries than federal ridings, or at the very least, they aren't the same by definition. I'm sure Canadians have city councils as well. I also don't know if federal ridings are systematically redistricting, but a quick Google shows they were redrawn in 2003 and 2013. Plus, I'm not sure why systematic redistricting would mean numbers. In fact, that almost sounds counterintuitive, since two very district areas could be California's 2nd between two cycles.

Comment: I'm open to other possibilities. It could also just be a cultural thing. For example, New Englanders in the U.S. often assign names to their houses and boats and cars, while people in the Midwest generally don't. New York City calls some public schools P.S. 34 for example, while no place else leaves schools unnamed. Some places name streets, others number them (again NYC).

Comment: US districts could also be at-large, meaning that they covered the entire state.  Or the rebellious US deliberately chose to use a different system than the UK/Great Britain.  The practice of numbering districts dates back to the first Congress (1789).  This seems more a historical question than a political one.

Comment: @Brythan, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canadian_federal_ridings, each of the three Canadian territories (YT, NU, NT) also have just 1 riding to them.

Comment: I would bet that less than 10% of the people who vote in the US know which district they live in.  It simply isn't that consequential at any time other than the election time.  It doesn't effect schools, medical care, postal codes or anything else that Canadians may associate with government services.  I would go further and bet that less than half of the people who vote in primary elections know the number of their district.  And primary voters are a  really small part of the population, but they are the most politically active part.

Comment: @grovkin I'm not sure I see where you're going with that

Comment: You mentioned that "it can be hard to remember where districts are."  And I wanted to point out that it doesn't tend to have any effect on everyday life.  If anything, it's mostly just a curiousity.

Comment: @grovkin  US at-large districts weren't necessarily one to a state.  I.e. some states had two or more at-large districts covering the same area.

Comment: @Brythan, oh, I misunderstood, then.  Could a state have both?  A few congressional districts based on geograhy and a few at-large?

Comment: @grovkin  In the days when they did that, yes.  Now, no.  That's part of what the One Person One Vote standard ended (outside of Senate seats which are constitutionally mandated).

Comment: @grovkin is correct.  I for example do not know the number of any of my districts, but I do know the names of my representatives in the US congress, the state assembly, the state senate, and the city council.  It is not particularly important to me which other neighborhoods or towns are also represented by those people.  I also know that I'm in election district 27 of my assembly district, because I need to know the number 27 to find the table where I pick up my ballot when I vote.  So even on election day, knowing the number of of my congressional district is not important or even helpful.

Comment: @phoog Well, how is any of that any different in Canada. My question came because I heard on the radio the race in the 6th district was heating up but I had no clue where the 6th district was.

Answer (score 2):

The United States Congress is a bicameral legislative body. It's made up of the Senate and House.

Senate districts do, in fact, use names to identify their constituencies. They are the names of the states. The "Senator for New York", for instance. Since these constituencies never change – it's always the people eligible to vote in the state – and there are only two senators from each state, using a name makes sense. Identifying senators by their named constituency is simple and easy.

House districts, however, have several important distinctions:

1. Multiple constituencies may co-exist in a single municipality.
2. A single constituency may cover multiple municipalities.
3. Constituencies may change after every [census](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Census).

Let's go over each one:

**1. Multiple constituencies may co-exist in a single municipality.**

The "Representative from New York City" is a term that applies to [13 members of Congress](https://www.quora.com/How-many-congressional-districts-are-in-the-New-York-City-area).

So using a name may often be too broad to identify a House member or his/her constituency.

---

**2. A single constituency may cover multiple municipalities.**

You mentioned California's 2nd. This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California%27s_2nd_congressional_district):

> Currently, the 2nd district encompasses the northern coast of the
> state. It stretches from the Golden Gate Bridge to the Oregon border
> and includes all of Highway 101 north of San Francisco except for a
> stretch in Sonoma County. It consists of Marin, Mendocino, Humboldt,
> Del Norte, and Trinity counties plus portions of Sonoma County. Cities
> in the district include San Rafael, Petaluma, Novato, Windsor,
> Healdsburg, Ukiah, Fort Bragg, Fortuna, Eureka, Arcata, McKinleyville,
> and Crescent City, California.

What in the world would you name this district? "California 2" is simple, and avoids the need for public hearings and a flurry of lawsuits from unhappy voters who feel left out or don't like the name.

It's worth noting that U.S House districts are substantially larger than [Canadian federal ridings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canadian_federal_ridings). Currently, the population of [a House district is about 720,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_apportionment#House_size) (based on the 2010 census). So using names for federal ridings is more feasible than for House districts.

---

**3. Constituencies may change after every census.**

As mandated by the U.S. Constitution ([Article I, Section 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Census)), the federal government conducts a population count every ten years for the purpose of determining the number of House seats allotted to each state.

Once these numbers are in, it is the responsibility of the state legislatures to re-draw House district boundaries. Often, this practice, known as [**redistricting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redistricting) or [**gerrymandering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering), has less to do with geography and more to do with politics – the lines are drawn to benefit the party in power.

(Redistricting is criticized by many because it often amounts to politicians picking their voters, as opposed to the other way around. But I digress.)

Redistricting means that House constituencies can change, making the named district people were accustomed to for the past decade inaccurate and obsolete. Again, a numerical ID keeps the district simple, easy and identifiable.

---

**All that said**, names are often used for House districts, but not officially. News media outlets often supplement the district number with geographic details.

[image]

Also, while the question states:

> In Canada, parliamentary ridings are given [names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canadian_federal_ridings), but in the US, members of Congress come from numbered districts, for example, California's 2nd.

... the [linked reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canadian_federal_ridings) shows that Canadian federal ridings are, in fact, numbered ("District code"), just like in the U.S.

[image]

Comment: I'll come back later with other comments  since I'm on my phone, but in my (brief) experience living in Canada they'd always say the name, never the "MP from Newfoundland 10001"

Comment: I think you may have a point regarding the size of a riding relative to a Congressional district. Congressional districts are two or three times larger in population so it is harder for them to be distinct, and my perception is that U.S. districts are also more gerrymandered.

Comment: In 1789, US House districts were only about 30,000 per.  The rest of this is also true of Canada.  E.g. Toronto is bigger than a federal riding, so they use neighborhood names as well.  Districts may cover multiple smaller municipalities.  Canada also has censuses every ten years.  "Manhattan, Brooklyn" is not like a Canadian name, which looks to be more West Manhattan/Borough Park.  Canadian names don't duplicate, and there are multiple districts in both Manhattan and Brooklyn.

Comment: All good points. My answer is based solely on personal observation and 10 minutes of research (I'd never even heard of "riding" before today). If you have something official or more accurate, you should post an answer. @Brythan

Comment: Isn't *gerrymandering* a subset of *redistricting*?  Or is the practice so widespread that the distinction is moot?

Comment: [Gerrymandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering) is redistricting with a focus on establishing an electoral advantage. Personally, I think it's a horrible practice. As I mentioned in my answer, it amounts to politicians choosing their voters, not the other way around. Plain redistricting would remove the political component from the re-drawing of lines.

Comment: For an example of gerrymandering see [North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering#Examples_of_gerrymandered_districts). For an example of plain redistricting see [Iowa](https://www.bostonglobe.com/news/politics/2013/12/08/iowa-redistricting-takes-partisanship-out-mapmaking/efehCnJvNtLMIAFSQ8gp7I/story.html). @DJohnM

Comment: Calling Iowa "plain redistricting" is missing some of the issues.  For example, at least two Iowa Representatives were forced to move or face other, same party incumbents.  And of course any form of geographic redistricting leaves almost half of the voters without a representative of their choice.  It's notable that Iowa is considered a swing state but 75% of its Representatives are Republican.

Comment: Iowa is plain redistricting, *vis-à-vis* gerrymandering, because an apolitical team of bureaucrats is tasked with drawing district boundaries, and they are expressly prohibited from considering any political factors, such as voter registration, historical voting patterns, and the home address of incumbents. When you remove all political considerations, as Iowa has done, you get clear polygonal districts and unvarnished ("plain") redistricting. @Brythan

Comment: #1 and #3 are true for Canada, the UK and presumably many other countries too, so I feel that they don't really address the question (for example, re #1: London alone contains [73 constituencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Parliamentary_constituencies_in_London), all with different names, and only one of which contains the word "London") . #2, however is a key difference. (In the UK, average people per constituency vary [from 57k in Wales to 72k in England](https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/constituencies/)).

Comment: Having said that, re #2: the UK's European Parliament constituencies are much bigger, and still have names - though they either encompass entire distinct regions (e.g. Scotland, London), or vague geographical areas (e.g. South East England). Why isn't that approach taken in the US?

Comment: So I'm not very convinced by most of your points: 1. *Multiple constituencies may co-exist in a single municipality.* This is not unique to the US. This map of federal ridings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canadian_federal_electoral_districts#/media/File:Canada_Federal_Ridings_Map.svg) shows that many Canadian cities are subdivided into federal ridings.

Comment: 2. *A single constituency may cover multiple municipalities.* Well, sure. This riding covers multiple BC municipalities: A single constituency may cover multiple municipalities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Vancouver%E2%80%94Sunshine_Coast%E2%80%94Sea_to_Sky_Country As for names, just off the top of my head: Klamath, Redwood. I suppose ridings are smaller, but I don't see how that leads to names being more feasible.

Comment: 3. *Constituencies may change after every census.* As far as I can tell, ridings are redistricted about as often as US House districts, although it doesn't seem to be a constitutional mandate in Canada, but I'm not an expert (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_district_(Canada)). And honestly, the fact that they change every ten years is an argument *against* unhelpful numbers. Look at what CA-2 used to look like:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California%27s_2nd_congressional_district#/media/File:CA-2nd.png ...

Comment: ... It's almost completely disjoint from the current district. If they were named "Shasta" and "Klamath," it would be far easier to keep them straight vs. remembering how much the district changed in 2013. Someone who doesn't move for 15 years could live in the 2nd district, then the 3rd, then the 6th. I don't see that as any better over names, but maybe you can explain your thoughts? Anyway, I'm not going to downvote, but there's really not much in this answer that passes the sniff test.

Comment: @AzorAhai Thanks for the feedback. My answer is a summary of my observations, analyses and possible reasons. I agree the points are debatable. After your detailed analysis and process of elimination, you seem well-suited to post a useful answer.